# Associative Array, Array and Tree

Tags: c++, arrays, tree, associative-array

I have two questions:
How can the Array Abstract data type be modified to implement an Associative Array?
How can the tree abstract data type be modified to implement an Associative Array?

Comment: These questions were in class materials. I read them but I could not find an appropriate answer to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an associative array out of an array, you'd typically start with an array of some sort of structure:

```
struct item {
    key_type key;
    value_type value;
};
```

Then you'd use `key`s to look up `value`s. For the sake of efficiency, you'd typically want to sort the array based on the `key`s, so you could use a binary search (or an interpolating search, if there's any degree of predictability to your key distribution).

For a tree, you'd do pretty much the same, except that for a tree a binary search is the default. You end up with a node pretty similar to that for an array, plus a couple of pointers:

```
struct node { 
    key_type key;
    value_type value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
```

Depending on the type of tree involved, you might also want another pointer to create a threaded tree and/or some balance information (e.g., for an AVL or R-B tree). Conversely, for a B-Tree you'd end up with arrays of nodes about like for the associative array, and link those together into a balanced tree.